# Disable searching in Python ObjectListView

Tags: python, wxpython, wxwidgets

I am using an ObjectListView in wxPython to present a few hundred to a few thousand records, each containing a character or two of text and a handful of numerical fields. I want to disable the typing search function of the ObjectListView as it is not very useful for my purposes and I want to use the keys for other things. However, I cannot work out how to disable all searching and not just shift it onto another column.

I suppose I could intercept a key press event and block the propagation, but that seems like a bit of a hack if there is a "right" way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find a "right" way to do this in the class docs, and blocking the event stopped accelerators in the main frame and cell editing working. However, if you bend the rules a bit, you can override `_FindByTyping` and do nothing, thereby cutting out all the searching code.

```
def _FindByTyping(self, searchColumn, prefix):
    pass
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting:

```
self.typingSearchesSortColumn = False
```

on your OLV instance?

And passing:

```
isSearchable=False
```

to all of your column definitions?

Both are set to true by default.

Comment: I did try both of these (and together). However, the [class docs](http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/python/majorClasses.html) say that `typingSearchesSortColumn=True` just means that typing searches in the currently sorted column rather than the "primary" column. `isSearchable=True` just means that if this column is sorted, it can be searched instead of column 0.